# I'd like to change img src internal links to external links

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

```
<div class="view-content">
<img src="/img/img_01.png">
<img src="/img/img_02.png">
<img src="/img/img_03.png">
</div>
```

If i wanna change this to

```
<div class="view-content">
<img src="http://example.com/img/img_01.png">
<img src="http://example.com/img/img_02.png">
<img src="http://example.com/img/img_03.png">
</div>
```

Like this with using javascript or php str replace
How can i do this.

```
var count = $('.view-content img').length; 
var url = window.location.hostname;
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
  var imgurl = $('.view-content').eq(i).attr('src'); 
  $('.view-content img').eq(i).append(url+'/'+imgurl);
}
```

I've alreay tried this code but it doesn't work at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use such simple script to add http at the begining of your src parameters for each image.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.view-content img')
images.forEach(item => {
  const src = item.getAttribute('src');
  const newSrc = 'http://example.com' + src;
  item.setAttribute('src', newSrc);
})
```

```html
<div class="view-content">
<img src="/img/img_01.png">
<img src="/img/img_02.png">
<img src="/img/img_03.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this snip can help, all I did was loop through the img elements; grabbed the SRC and stored in a temp var; appended the http:// domain + the src as the new source attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title></title>

    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <h1 class="mt-5">Test</h1>
            <img src="/img/img_01.png">
            <img src="/img/img_02.png">
            <img src="/img/img_03.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("img").each(function(){
          var src = $(this).attr('src');
          $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.blah.com' + src);
        })
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on a theme perhaps

```
let host='http://example.com/';
let col=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
col.forEach( img =>{
    if( !~img.src.indexOf( host ) )img.src = host + img.src;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what about just switching it manually in js with id's?

```
document.getElementById("1stPic").src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HS0VtcX.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you need a new base URL for *all* the links on a page, you can avoid JS completely and use the `<base>` element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base